# SSL advantages worth the hassle?

Tags: authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate

Currently using a Godaddy SSL on http://www.spothero.com

On a friend's iphone it said "cannot verify server identity"

Two people I know cannot access it from their blackberrys and server identity problems keep popping up even on browsers on computers.

Are the advantages of SSL worth this hassle?  What would be the downside of completely getting rid of the HTTPS connection?

Comment: Loosing security? Of course if you don't transmit sensitive data, you don't need it imo.

Comment: If you have sensitive data to protect, SSL is a must. See e.g. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/breaking-the-webs-cookie-jar.html

Comment: See also for heated discussion on SO's policy towards this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69171/why-doesnt-the-stack-overflow-team-fix-the-firesheep-style-cookie-theft

Answer (score 4):

For a certificate to be considered valid for web it must:

- Not be expired
- Not be issued after the current date
- Be issued to the viewing domain
- Be issued for the purpose of server authentication
- The certificate chain must be trusted

The problem you are likely seeing is related to the last requirement, your certificates are issued from the Go Daddy certificate authority (CA) and therefore the "system" accessing your site must be aware of and trust that certificate(s).

Windows and other operating systems come pre bundled with a whole load of CA certificates pre trusted so users of these systems will be able to access your site without any warnings (unless they have untrusted the CA).  The chances are the blackberry / iphone operating system do not have the Go Daddy CA certs pre trusted so a user would have to add this manually (something the vats majority of users will not know how to do)

That explains the issues you are seeing, as for the "hassle" question that largely depends on what Spothero will be doing when it goes live.  If it requires users to submit private/personal/sensitive information then yes it should have an HTTPs component when this data is being submitted/displayed.  If Spothero will never use private etc information then you don't really need SSL.

So going back to the cause of your issue, if you decide you really need SSL (to give your users peace of mind) then consider using better known Certificate Authority such as Verisign or Thwaites.

Comment: The information submitted would be an email address and password.  Payment information would be handled by amazon.                         Going back to the root problem, is it commonly known that Godaddy is not a well known Certificate Authority?

Comment: An email address being known is hardly a security breach IMHO, and good practice would be to not pass the password in clear text to the server (the general rule is to use a salted md5 hash created on the client).  So I would say that you don't "need" SSL - that said it is something that can give users peace of mind and also give your site a certain about of credibility - these of course are entirely subjective and somewhat misinformed but the truth is that is what Joe Public thinks.

Answer (score 4):

There's actually a well-understood (if not widely practiced) way to handle this question.

Recall that the mathematical definition of *risk* is

> *R* = *P* × *H*

where *R* is the risk, *P* is the probability of the bad thing happening, and *H* is the *hazard*, ie, the cost of that bad thing if it happens.

Make an estimate of how much a bad disclosure could cost you, in currency.  Figure out the probability that someone would try it (anything from a wild-ass guess to  a careful analysis) and succeed, and you can compute *R*.

Is *R* less than the cost of solving your SSL problem?  If so, it's not worth the effort.

Now, that said, the complaint you're getting means the certificate you're using for your SSL is not signed by a known trusted source, eg Verisign.  If GoDaddy sold you the SLL and cert, then it's a tech support problem for them.  Otherwise, you need to buy a verifiable cert.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is important if you're sending sensitive data across, such as usernames and passwords.

I see that your certificate's verifying authority is GoDaddy itself, which may not be so popular. A better option might be to go for Verisign's or Thawte's.

Comment: Is there even a purpose of going with Godaddy?  If the certificate needs to be manually added to the root, why even bother getting an SSL?

Comment: Also, it seems that for just user names and passwords, most places don't have https for login unless it is sensitive information for like an address or at a banking website.  For example, twitter, aol, facebook... unless Im missing something...

Comment: @Mark: `If the certificate needs to be manually added to the root, why even bother getting an SSL?` <-- I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, it's true that twitter, etc do not normally use SSL. However, as others have pointed out, this makes it far easier for a hacker to sniff out traffic and impersonate users.

Answer (score 0):

With the widespread usage of tools like FireSheep, it's extremely important to use SSL if you ever use public WiFi networks. It's extremely easy to snoop and to impersonate users by copying their session cookies.

Comment: Firesheep is only useful if the user is accessing the site via an unsecured network. It doesn't seem like SSL is a standard on most websites for login.  Is there another security protocol that websites like twitter, facebook, and aol use?

Comment: @Mark those sites are going to switch to SSL sooner or later. It's just a huge investment everyone is reluctant to make. GMail now fully supports SSL